# Transfering AWS S3/Cloudfront/iAm between User Accounts

Tags: amazon-aws, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Rails site that makes heavy use of S3 and Cloudfront, with a non-trivial setup including multiple buckets for each environment (dev, staging production) and heavily tweaked Cloudfront configuration to support HTTPS and other features. I have staging and production Heroku apps that host the Rails apps.

I am no longer going to host or manage this site so I need to hand-off to a different company. For my Heroku account it is as simple as adding an account for the new company to the apps and removing my own. However there seems to be no clear way of transferring or even duplicating the S3 buckets and Cloudfront configuration to a different user account.

Obviously I can dump the contents of the S3 buckets so they can be uploaded to new buckets, but how can I transfer all the button configuration (permissions etc) and all the Cloudfront settings?

Comment: One easy solution might be transferring you whole AWS account to another company: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/transfer-aws-account/

Comment: Unfortunately I have many other projects using S3, Cloudfront etc on that account.